# About $\log$-convex functions

Tags: calculus, limits, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ be a $\log$-convex function such that 
the sequence $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}$ is convergent. Then,

is it true that for every $r>0$, the function $\frac{f(x+r)}{f(x)}$ has a limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Let $g=\log(f)$. Then $g$ is convex, so if $n+1\le x$ and $x+r\le m$ we have $$g(n+1)-g(n)\le\frac{g(x+r)-g(x)}{r}\le g(m+1)-g(m).$$Hence $\lim_n(g(n+1)-g(n))=L$ implies $\lim_x(g(x+r)-g(x))=rL$.

**First version:**
We cheat and assume that $f$ is differentiable. Let $g=\log(f)$ and $h=g'$. Since $g$ is convex, $h$ is non-decreasing. So $\lim_{t\to\infty}h(t)$ exists, although it could *a priori* be infinite.

But the hypothesis says that $\int_{n}^{n+1}h\to L\in \mathbb R$. So $\lim_{t\to\infty}h(t)=L$. Hence $\int_x^{x+r}h\to rL$.

One could presumably translate that into an argument using just convexity of $g$, without assuming differentiability. Or one could probably approximate $g$ by a convolution of $g$ with an approximate idenity.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think so. Could you please give an explicit proof.

Comment: Are you saying you have problems with the proof assuming differentiability, or that you don't see how it can be extended to the non-differentiable case?

Comment: the non-differentiable case

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand See the revised version of the answer.

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich. Could you also see another related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2519665/inequalities-for-a-real-2-convex-function